# How can I append a None value to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, append, nonetype

I have a list :

```
A = ['Yes']
```

I want to have

```
A = ['Yes',None]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use `append`:

```
A.append(None)

>>> print A
['Yes', None]
```

Comment: @user1734229: You might have done something like `print(A.append(None))`.

Answer (score 10):

Simple:

```
A.append(None)
```

or

```
A += [None]
```

or

```
A.extend([None])
```

or

```
A[len(A):] = [None]
```