# Append a null into a list in python

Tags: python, list, null

If I have a list:

```
ex_list = [x,y,z]
```

but I want to have

```
[x, y, z, ]
```

How do I do it? I tried:

```
ex_list.append(None)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Sure `ex_list.append(None)` doesn't work? It should

Comment: What does [x,y,z,] mean? It's a four element array with ... what? Note that (x,y,z,) is valid tuple syntax, but it's just 3-element

Comment: I confirm here, just tried out of surprise and it does work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I append a None value to a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238489/how-can-i-append-a-none-value-to-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @en_Knight: and `[x, y, z,]` is valid list syntax, just three elements.

Answer (score 11):

The concept of null does not exist in Python. The closest related idea would be `None`, which can be appended just as you indicated:

```
ex_list.append(None)
```

which would result in

```
[x, y, z, None]
```